# Adding constraints to child view controllers in IB

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout

iOS dev newbie question:

I've been playing around with autolayout and constraints in IB and more or less got the hold of it when setting constraints for views in the same view controller.

What confuses me is how to set constraints in IB if you want to use view controller containment: How do you establish "autolayout relationships" in IB between views of different child view controllers of the same parent view controller?

Basically what I want is a root view controller that contains 2 child view controllers. On iPad in portrait mode I want one view controller at the top and the other one beneath it. On iPad in landscape mode I want one view controller on the left and the other one on the right. Kind of a split view controller but with both view controllers always present no matter the orientation.

I've been able to achieve this with views in the same view controller but have no idea how to do the same thing if i want those views "embedded" in their own view controllers.

This is my first question on stack overflow, so please tell me if I've ignored any rules about how to post questions.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you adding constrain programatically or in storyboard? Also can you please post snap of your view/xib if you already tried to add constrain?

Comment: That's the point: I want to set the constraints in IB to avoid having to add them programatically. I understand how to do it with two views in the same controller as you can create constraints between them in IB. But you can't create constraints in IB between views in different view controllers (the view controllers that would be embedded in the root view controller).

Comment: Sorry, not enough reputation to post images...

Comment: I think that can be possible through programming only.

Comment: Child view controllers have views and those views are subviews of a parent view controllers view. You can create views for subviews so I'm not following the confusion?

Comment: And if you want to have constraints for iPad landscape and portrait you have to do that programmatically since an iPad is Regular-Regular in all orientations

Comment: For example: a split view controller on an iPad in portrait mode has one of its view controller's view on the left and the other view controller's view on the right. Is it possible to set constraints between those two views in IB? Control-dragging from one VC's view to the other VC's view is not possible. Sorry I'm not able to explain better. I'm a total newbie and probably trying to do something which should be done with a totally different approach...

Comment: Sorry, in my last comment I meant iPad in landscape, not portrait...